# How to add AWS credential key to Hadoop configuration in intelliJ

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop

I was trying to perform operations with Hadoop via IntelliJ with AWS but having a problem of Hadoop -no access to my credential key.
My IntelliJ account already connect to AWS and I am able to use these services, but with Hadoop, I encountered the following problem.

This is the code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String s3Path = "adoop-map-reduce-collocation-extraction/corpus-cardinality-by-decade";
    String output = "s3a://adoop-map-reduce-collocation-extraction/statistic-extraction";

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("CorpusCardinalityFilePath", s3Path);

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Appearances Calculation");
    job.setJarByClass(AppearancesCalculation.class);
    job.setMapperClass(AC_Mapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(AC_Combiner.class);
    job.setReducerClass(AC_Reducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(nGramKey.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(nGramKey.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(nGramValue.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inPath));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(output));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

and all dependencies -

3.0.0

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.531</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations-java5</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

This is the whole error -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.InterruptedIOException: doesBucketExist on
>   adoop-map-reduce-collocation-extraction:
>   com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS Credentials provided by
>   BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider
>   InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException:
>   Unable to load credentials from service endpoint  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(FileOutputFormat.java:182)
>     at AppearancesCalculation.main(AppearancesCalculation.java:153)
>   Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: doesBucketExist on
>   adoop-map-reduce-collocation-extraction:
>   com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS Credentials provided by
>   BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider
>   InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException:
>   Unable to load credentials from service endpoint  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(FileOutputFormat.java:178)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS
>   Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider
>   EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider
>   InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException:
>   Unable to load credentials from service endpoint  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSCredentialProviderList.getCredentials(AWSCredentialProviderList.java:151)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1225)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:801)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:751)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4914)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketRegionViaHeadRequest(AmazonS3Client.java:5693)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.fetchRegionFromCache(AmazonS3Client.java:5666)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4898)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4860)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1394)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1333)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:320)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to
>   load credentials from service endpoint    at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.handleError(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:183)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:162)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.getCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:82)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSCredentialProviderList.getCredentials(AWSCredentialProviderList.java:129)
>     ... 26 more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed
>   out   at
>   java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:148)
>     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)   at
>   java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
>     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)
>     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)   at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)    at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1224)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1203)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:991)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.internal.ConnectionUtils.connectToEndpoint(ConnectionUtils.java:54)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:113)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:82)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider$InstanceMetadataCredentialsEndpointProvider.getCredentialsEndpoint(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:197)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:122)
>     ... 29 more Disconnected from the target VM, address:
>   '127.0.0.1:60790', transport: 'socket'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Looking the error I would say you need to add the file core-site.xml to your resources with the properties `fs.s3a.access.key`, `fs.s3a.secret.key` and `fs.s3a.endpoint`